# MySQL Join: Conditions in WHERE or in ON (2)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I would like to know if putting the conditions for `JOIN` in the `ON ()` clause is better, for maintaining, than in the latter `WHERE`.

Example:

```
Select * from persons p
  INNER JOIN x on (x.id = p.id AND x.other = p.other)

Select * from persons p
  INNER JOIN x on (x.id = p.id)
WHERE x.other = p.other
```

Here seems good, but with multiple JOINs, its more difficult, I think:

```
Select * from persons p
  INNER JOIN x on (x.id = p.id)
  INNER JOIN x2 on (x2.id = p.id)
  INNER JOIN x3 on (x3.id = p.id)
WHERE x.other = p.other AND x2.other = p.other2 AND x3.other = p.other3

Select * from persons p
  INNER JOIN x on (x.id = p.id AND x.other = p.other)
  INNER JOIN x2 on (x2.id = p.id AND x2.other = p.other2)
  INNER JOIN x3 on (x3.id = p.id AND x3.other = p.other3)
```

I have a test with an app that I'm developing and switching the conditions produces the same execution plan, thought I don't know if I'm missing something, or if I can find performance impact in some situations.

Thanks

**EDIT: It is not the same as the question being marked as duplicated. I do not ask difference between JOIN and WHERE. I ask difference of putting conditions in WHERE and not in ON clause when using a JOIN statement.**

As I said in a comment in my previous question, shouldn't be faster for the second JOIN to  process the already filtered data than for WHERE to process all the data later?

Comment: Where are you getting the p2 and p3 aliases from in your second query?

Comment: You should always use ANSI syntax JOINs because the condition is more explicit and easier to maintain. ANSI JOIN separates criteria from relationship condition

Comment: The quick way to think about the placement of the joins is that when you `join` using `on()`, you are creating a "temporary table" that is already returning the paired down results you are asking it to. If you `join` in the `where`, you are asking for the entire table and then doing your filtering after you have received every piece of data.

In small applications you won't see a performance hit, but if you were working with live data or thousands and thousands of rows, you'd know right away.

Comment: Your previous question had several votes to be reopened pending, because you are correct it was incorrectly closed against the one about join syntax.

Comment: Apart from the ease of maintenance and being more readable (which should be enough by themselves), the main difference is the stage at which the condition is applied. When you apply the condition inside `JOIN` condition (`ON`/`USING`) - the condition is actually applied during the construction of the combined result set. Whereas in the other case (`WHERE` clause) - the condition is applied only after the result set is constructed...

Answer (score 0):

The difference between putting conditions on your joins versus putting them in the where clause is the shape of the data in each query.

Let's assume that you have 1000 rows in your persons table, 800 rows in x, 600 rows in x2, and 500 rows in x3 that match the persons.id JOIN conditions you've specified.

In this query:

```
Select * from persons p
  INNER JOIN x on (x.id = p.id)
  INNER JOIN x2 on (x2.id = p.id)
  INNER JOIN x3 on (x3.id = p.id)
WHERE x.other = p.other AND x2.other = p.other2 AND x3.other = p.other3
```

By the time you reach the WHERE clause you are evaluating 500 rows on the conditions you've specified.

Whereas in this query:

```
Select * from persons p
  INNER JOIN x on (x.id = p.id AND x.other = p.other)
  INNER JOIN x2 on (x2.id = p.id AND x2.other = p2.other)
  INNER JOIN x3 on (x3.id = p.id AND x3.other = p3.other)
```

You may still end up evaluating 500 rows in the worst case scenario (all of the x.other = p.other conditions evaluate to TRUE), but most likely you will end up evaluating fewer rows by the time you reach your last join.